# Check if the id is present in the JsonField(list) passed to OutRef during Django subquery filtering

Tags: python, django, orm, django-orm

If I have 2 models related through a JsonField(list),I am annotating a queryset of Foos with bars in this list

```
class Foo(Model):
    bar_list = models.JSONField(default=list)

class Bar(Model):
    id = IntegerField()


bar_query = Bar.objects.filter(id__in=OuterRef('bar_list')).values("id")[:1]

foos_with_bar_id = Foo.objects.all().annotate(task_id=Subquery(bar_query))
```

but it doesn't work.
I get a error"django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near..."
But when i relplace the "OuterRef" to a specified list, like[1,2,3], It works. So does OuterRef not support JsonField?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, OuterRef is not supported for filtering on JSONField in some databases, including MySQL (it is on Postgres, for example).

A fix could be to use Subquery to explicitly cast the JSONField to a list in the subquery:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
from django.db.models import F, Subquery, OuterRef, IntegerField

bar_query = Bar.objects.filter(id__in=Cast(OuterRef('bar_list'), output_field=IntegerField())).values("id")[:1]
foos_with_bar_id = Foo.objects.all().annotate(task_id=Subquery(bar_query))
```

The Cast function is used to explicitly cast the bar_list from JSONField to IntegerField in the subquery.

Have a look at the [Django db docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield) for any specific considerations related to database backend.

Comment: Thx, But this fix seems doesn't work, Can a List be converted to an Integer?

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't able to try the full query. The purpose of using output_field=IntegerField() in the bar_query was to explicitly cast the JSONField (bar_list) to an IntegerField, but I understand from your test that is not working. Have you already tried using values_list instead of values in the original query?

Comment: It also was not work.But I had decided to use an alternative method, which using multiple database queries to avoid the use of subqueries.

Comment: Please post your solution, also if at the moment it is just partial and incomplete, it could be very useful and I'm happy to support reviewing it!

Comment: Like this
```
foos_with_bar_list = Foo.objects.all().values("bar_list")
for foo in foos_with_bar_list:
  bar_ids = Bars.object.filter(id__in=foo["bar_list"]).values("id")
```

Answer (score 0):

Django can't use OuterRef with JSONFields because it can't convert it into a proper SQL query for the JSON data.
To solve this, you have to find a different way, like modifying the model or managing the filtering/annotation in Python instead of the database.